# PowerBI - Analyze in Excel - Weird error message when changing a filter

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Here's the deal.

I have a PowerBI report that people usually consume by using the "analyze in Excel" function.
The thing is that there are some attributes (not all) from a particular table that follow this pattern:

- You can add them as a filter
- You can select one (or more values) and it filters properly.
- When you want to change that filter, you get this message:

Query (1, 92) The syntax for 's' is incorrect. ( WITH MEMBER [Measures].cChildren As ‘AddCalculatedMembers((Resource Plan Attributes).[User's DOA Level].currentmember.children).count’ Set
FilteredMembers As ‘{[Resource Plan Attributes).[User''s DOA Level].&:(E02), [Resource Plan Attributes).[User's DOA Level].&(E03)}' Select {{Measures].cChildren} on ROWS, Hierarchize(Generate(FilteredMembers,
Ascendants((Resource Plan Attributes).[User's DOA Level].currentmember))) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, MEMBER_TYPE ON COLUMNS FROM [Model] ).

I've been looking around all day and I cannot figure out why some columns do this and some don't. I don't even understand the message.
Has anyone seen anything like this?

Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your name of column/measure; you should remove the apostrophe.

[User's DOA Level]

Comment: Oh my god, why on earth didn't I see this?? Thank you so much!!